# Vagrant machine wont run SED correctly - How to escape backslashes in Vagrant shell scripts

Tags: ruby, sed, vagrant

I have a problem I can't get around with vagrant provisioning. I have a file that has backslashes in it that I need to remove but Vagrant (Ruby?) just won't do it and I have tried for 2 days now.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|  
%w{test2 }.each_with_index do |name, i|
config.vm.define name do |node|
 node.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
   vb.name = "test#{i + 2}"
   vb.memory = 512
   vb.cpus = 1
 end
 node.vm.box = "ubuntu/focal64"
 node.disksize.size = "1GB"
 node.vm.hostname = name
 node.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.0.5.#{i + 12}"
 node.vm.provision :shell, privileged: false, inline: <<-SHELL       
   cat /vagrant/control_join_file.sh | tr -d '\\n' > /vagrant/control_join_file#{i + 12}.sh       
   sed -i -E "s@\\@ @" /vagrant/control_join_file#{i + 12}.sh
   chmod +x /vagrant/control_join_file#{i + 12}.sh 
   sudo /vagrant/control_join_file#{i + 12}.sh 
 SHELL
end
end      
end
```

The line below is the culprit if I comment it out the provision happens.

```
sed -i -E "s@\\@ @" /vagrant/control_join_file#{i + 12}.sh
```

I changed the delimiter to @ sign and have tried hundreds of things. I am really hoping someone can point out what's wrong here.

Also If I run it like this it works. I can look into the created file and sure enough the 4's are changed to percent signs. The issue seems to be with backslashes.

```
sed -i -E "s@4@%@" /vagrant/control_join_file#{i + 12}.sh
```

Comment: Did you try the regular thing, doubling the backslashes? `sed -i -E "s@\\\\@ @" /vagrant/control_join_file#{i + 12}.sh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue turns out to be more complex than you would think. The problem is that you have three stages of string interpolation going on here. Each stage needs strings and backslashes escaped properly in order for the final `sed` command to be correct:

1. **Ruby** does string interpolation on the heredoc `<<-SHELL` string.
2. The **shell** under which the script is executed does its own interpolation.
3. **Sed** does its own interpolation on the regular expression you provide.

Let's work backwards starting from stage 3, so that we know what the end requirements are before we begin with the other stages.

**Stage 3 - Sed**

We know that sed requires the backslash to be escaped in its regular expression. So the sed command needs the following string `s/\\/ /`.

The question then becomes: how do we feed exactly that string to sed?

**Stage 2 - The Shell**

We KNOW we have to feed two backslashes to sed. Let's run some test in the shell and see how it escapes backslashes:

```
$ echo "\\"
\
```

Aha. It turns out the shell (bash) interpolates backslashes inside double quotes. What about single quotes?

```
$ echo '\\'
\\
```

Well that's useful. It means we can use single quotes to prevent backslash interpolation in Bash.

Let's test it:

```
$ echo '\\' | sed -E 's/\\/X/'
X\
```

It seems to work. Note that if you want to replace all backslashes, you need to use the `g` modifier:

```
$ echo '\\' | sed -E 's/\\/X/g'
XX
```

Ok. It seems we have gathered all the puzzle pieces for moving to stage 1.

**Stage 1 - Ruby**

In Ruby the heredoc `<<-SHELL` operator does its own string interpolation. Therefore backslashes need to be escaped.

Let's test it in `irb`:

```
> puts <<-SHELL
sed -E 's/\\\\/ /' ...
SHELL

sed -E 's/\\/ /' ...
```

Looks good!

What we learned so far:

1. Ruby heredoc `<<-SHELL` requires backslashes to be escaped.
2. The shell (Bash or sh), requires backslashes to be escaped, **unless single quotes are used**.
3. Sed needs two backslashes.

Now we can assemble our script properly:

```
node.vm.provision :shell, privileged: false, inline: <<-SHELL
  ...
  sed -i -E 's/\\\\/ /' /vagrant/control_join_file#{i + 12}.sh
  ...
SHELL
```

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I have to say that in some way I had already tried it (tried up to 8 backslashes) but it did not work so I kept going. I must have just had one piece of the puzzle missing. but thanks to you now I have it working as it should! I know it took your time away but I want you to know that I really appreciate your detailed answer.